# How To Quiet Drools Resource Scanner Logging?

Tags: java, logging, drools

I am using Drool's resource scanner like so:

```
ResourceChangeScannerConfiguration sconf = ResourceFactory.getResourceChangeScannerService().newResourceChangeScannerConfiguration();
sconf.setProperty("drools.resource.scanner.interval", "5");
ResourceFactory.getResourceChangeScannerService().configure(sconf);
ResourceFactory.getResourceChangeScannerService().start();
ResourceFactory.getResourceChangeNotifierService().start();
```

Which works well, but the problem is that is logs to the console way too much:

```
[2011:10:284 12:10:913:debug] ResourceChangeScanner thread is waiting for 5
[2011:10:284 12:10:915:debug] ResourceChangeScanner attempt to scan 4 resources
[2011:10:284 12:10:915:debug] ResourceChangeScanner scanning directory=[UrlResource path='file:repository/entitlement/static-rules/']
[2011:10:284 12:10:915:debug] ResourceChangeScanner scanning directory=[UrlResource path='file:repository/entitlement/rules/']
[2011:10:284 12:10:915:debug] ResourceChangeScanner thread is waiting for 5
[2011:10:284 12:10:917:debug] ResourceChangeScanner attempt to scan 4 resources
[2011:10:284 12:10:917:debug] ResourceChangeScanner scanning directory=[UrlResource path='file:repository/entitlement/static-rules/']
[2011:10:284 12:10:917:debug] ResourceChangeScanner scanning directory=[UrlResource p
```

Every 5 seconds, a new set of lines. Any idea how to quiet it down a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
ResourceFactory.getResourceChangeNotifierService().
      setSystemEventListener(new DoNothingSystemEventListener());
```

BTW this is the default listener, don't know why `org.drools.agent.impl.PrintStreamSystemEventListener` is picked up in your case.

Comment: We had to update our version of Drools, but it worked like a charm. Thanks! There will the many happy console users now~