# Drools Log files

Tags: logging, drools, processmodel

I am beginner in JBPM and Drools, and I don't know where I can trace the error messages from the drools engine when I am running my deployed application (Process Model with user tasks and Business Rules). Anybody can tell me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory`](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.2/javadocs/org/drools/logger/KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory.html):

```
KnowledgeRuntimeLogger logger = 
   KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory.newFileLogger(ksession, "logdir/mylogfile");
```

## See also

- [How To Quiet Drools Resource Scanner Logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729399)